# SIGSEGV occurred using signed mkBV2Int

Tags: macos, z3, bitvector

The following code leads to a SIGSEV

```
Map<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
settings.put("model", "true");
Context z3_ctx = new Context(settings);
BitVecExpr bv_left = z3_ctx.mkBV(10, 32);
IntExpr ret_val = z3_ctx.mkBV2Int(bv_left, true);
```

If signed==false, then no problem happens.

I am running Z3 on a MAC OS X.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of Z3 do you use? I remember fixing a bug with the same symptoms some time ago, but so far the fix is only available in the `unstable` branch of Z3.

Comment: I am using `Z3 [version 4.3.2 - 64 bit]. (C) Copyright 2006 Microsoft Corp.`

Comment: Since you don't have the git hash in the version information you probably compiled it yourself. Did you get the sources before or after this fix? https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/9c052f589d7a535ea46837f1feff095e57cfc878

Comment: I upgraded Z3 to the unstable branch and the segmentation fault does not happen any longer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for letting us know!